# Vertices that are K away

Tags: graph-algorithms

Given a graph **G(V,E)** and a vertex **v**, how do i find all the vertices that are reachable via simple paths ( no vertex on the path repeats) of length exactly **k**.

Powers of adjacency matrix gives the number of paths between vertices but it includes non simple paths.

Is this problem solvable in polynomial time ? If not are there any known approximation algorithms. Any pointers to literature would be great.

Comment: Is it possible to move the question between different stack sites ? I may not have enough reputation to do this.

Comment: Somebody can do it, but as far as I can tell, I don't have enough reputation to do it either. :-/

Comment: assume you have a triangle formed by v, A, and B. With k=2, are both A and B what you are looking for?

Comment: Seems this belongs on CS.StackExchange not SO, not CSTheory

Comment: A classical breadth-first search algorithm of depth $k$ doesn't make it?

Comment: @Lamine, he doesn't look for shortest path, so BFS is wrong, and this is NPC problem. just set K to n-1, it's as hard as Hamiltonian path problem.